# Azure Website - only available to other resources (websites) in the same resource group?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-security

Azure doesn't provide outbound IP addresses for websites, so it's not possible to restrict access to a website by an IP address that is specifically reserved for a particular website within your azure ecosystem.

Is there another way to make a website/web app only available to resources within it's resource group such that it's not available publicly?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "native" way to do that, but you could implement various work arounds:

1. [Use authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-web%2ftoc.json)
2. [Use mutual SSL authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth)
3. Use your own custom authorization